# Making small bunch of file lists for Argument list too long error

Tags: linux, shell

When I try like this,

```
convmv -r -f utf8 --nfd -t utf8 --nfc /data/MyVid/Myfile/* --notest
```

There comes error here.

```
convmv: Argument list too long
```

I guess * indicates too many files.

So, if I can separate these files into small bunches.

Is there any good way to do this?

for example I try like this , `ls -la | convmv -r -f utf8 --nfd -t utf8 --nfc`

However it doesn't pass the file to convmv.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `xargs`:

```bash
find /path/to/dir | xargs convmv -r -f utf8 --nfd -t utf8 --nfc
```

Comment: Some how it doesn't work correctly,  such as `Unknown option: S
Unknown option: h
Unknown option: n
Unknown option: c
Unknown option: h
Unknown option: ?
Unknown option: ?
Unknown option: ?
Unknown option: ?
Unknown option: ?`

Some illegular letters prevent the convmv....?

Comment: `find /path/to/dir | xargs -0 convmv -r -f utf8 --nfd -t utf8 --nfc` might work better. The `-0` flag allows `xargs` to deal with whitespaces in filenames if there are any.